# DateTime period issues

Tags: php, datetime

I've got strange behaviour with datetime's in php.
For some reason this code produces wrong result:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime('2017-03-20'),
            DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'),
            new DateTime('2017-03-31')
        );
foreach($period as $dt){
  $a[] = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

So expected result is period from 20 to 31, but it's not. Here is actual result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-03-20
    [1] => 2017-03-21
    [2] => 2017-03-22
    [3] => 2017-03-23
    [4] => 2017-03-24
    [5] => 2017-03-25
    [6] => 2017-03-26
    [7] => 2017-03-27
    [8] => 2017-03-28
    [9] => 2017-03-29
    [10] => 2017-03-30
)
```

So what i'm missing here, or that's a php bug?

Comment: The end date is not included in the period. This is how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this user statement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#109846) on official PhP documentation about `DatePeriod::`

> [...] an example to include the end date using the DateTime method 'modify'

This class seems to ignore the end date. You will need to modify the end date to include this gap (of +1 unit, in your case +1 day).